# HTML5 Audio autoplay on Android - iframe trick

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio, iframe

I'm using audio tag from iframe to play automatically in Android to avoid disallowing autoplay in mobile devices. There are 2 works, one is working well and the other is not working. I'll write two all cases below.

**CASE 1. Well Working Case**

I have a form like this in main html file,

```
<form id='form' name='form' method='post'>
<input type='text' id='data' name='data'></input>
<input type='button' id='subSen' value='Submit'></input><br/>
</form>
```

And, have an iframe which plays audio

```
<iframe src="./play.jsp" width='30' height='10'></iframe>
```

In play file, I'm using javascript like this,

```
  var audio;// = document.getElementById('tts');
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        audio = $('#tts')
        .attr('src', 'src');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
        console.log('play');
    }, false);
  });
```

To invoke javascript in play file, I'm using this code in main html file

```
$(function() {
    iframeWindow = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
    $('#subSen').on('click', function() {
        var params = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: './runner.jsp',
            data: params,
            name: name,
            async: false,   // Disable asynchronous to wait until ajax finishes
            success: function(data) {
                //** get data from runner as var result **//
                iframeWindow.postMessage(result, '*');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that #subSen is an input typed button

When I click button or send enter key, it sends message to play file inside ajax success **(with iframeWindow.postMessage())** and audio works well on both Chrome on PC and Chrome on Android.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#subSen").click();
        }
    });
}, 0);
```

============ END OF WELL WORKING CASE ============

But problem is here

**CASE 2. Not Working Case**

I'm using Speech Recognition in my project, so in main file, I used code like this,

(this code is in the same $(function() {}) from above)

```
$(function() {
    iframeWindow = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow;
    isSR = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition || null;
    if(isSR == null) {
        alert("Speech Recognition not supported");
    }
    else {
        sr = new isSR();

        sr.lang = 'en';
        sr.onresult = function(event) {
            for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
                //console.log(i+' '+event.results[i][0].transcript);
                var data = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                $('#data').val(data);
                $('#area').append('You('+name+'): '+$('#data').val(data)+'\n');
                $("#subSen").click();
            }
        }

        sr.onend = function(event) {
            console.log('onend');
            sr.start();
        }
    }
    sr.start();
});
```

I expected that button click event **($('#subSen').click())** will invoke message into iframe like when I pushes Enter key on my keyboard. Of course it works well in PC, but not playing any sound in Android.

**(*Please note that Speech Recognition and runner inside ajax are well working on both PC and Android)**

Data is passed well on Android, but sound is not playing. Is there any way to play audio automatically in this case?

- Final note, Problem on Android occurs when I first get into page. If I play any sound with audio tag before using SR, it works well from then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that $.on() function must be used to invoke audio from iframe...

and it does not work on FireFox for Android.